# Issue with Ag grid implementation in Angula2

Tags: angular2-forms, ag-grid

It was a very big problem to me please help me, I am using ag grid to show the Data Base data for retrieving purpose it is working fine, but when i am editing the data of existing records , edited data is not binding to component.ts file. I mean if i enter any new column or modify the existing column the data is not reflecting in to the component.ts.(In Angular2 terminology it is similar to two way data binding).

Comment: A simple example would help. I have had no problem adjusting the data and  I have a multi-layer grid. When you change data in the grid your row souce changes but this may not be the data you are pushing into the grid as the grid has no knowledge of that. Perhaps try using one of the events to pick up the data has changed and keep things in sync yourself (if you are really lazy just get the grid data and slap it on your primary component?

Comment: Hi Matrim thank you very much for your answer can you provide a example of it, because i have worked in many ways to resolve the problem but i am unable to do it, So Please Provide example or provide any link for the example

Comment: lol, if you want a working example just grab the demo code from the ag-grid web site and run (and look) at that. If you are unwilling to generate an example showing the failure then it kind of disincentivises other people from doing the same for you..